# Compilation Speed: Should I add gem or include js/css files in my rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, asset-pipeline

For example, I want to add `datepicker` feature in my rails app. I have both options, that is, I can **install** `bootstrap-datepicker` **rails gem** or **download** datepicker files and **include** in my project. Which is the better approach with respect to security and compilation/page load speed?

Answer (score 6):

Rails is all about following conventions and make life easier. The prefer way would be include a gem and require it in `application.js` file. The other options would be including from a live CDN or download manually and include in the assets folder which does not seems to be a right choice.

Reasons:

- If you download manually and include it in the assets folder, then
  in future if you ever need to upgrade to a latest version, you will
  need to repeat the process of downloading the file and include the
  assets folder.
- If you include from a live CDN, this will make your layout
  file(`application.html.erb`) messy. You are going against assets
  pipeline to minimise http requests which slower down the speed of
  page rendering. Also you will have to repeat the same process of
  updating URLs to upgrade to a latest version.

So its better to use gems and easy to change versions. You can change version of any library in the gem file.